# Mongodb: use $project to get field from first element of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two models: `Movie` and `Author`.
I'm using the aggregation framework to make a join and add author name to each movie:

```
[
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "authors",
            "localField": "author_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "author"

        }

    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "author": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$author", 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "author_name": "$author.name"
        }
    }
]
```

It is posible to get `author_name` without to use two `$project`?

Comment: Use $let operator in project stage. Something like `"author_name": {$let:{vars: {author:{"$arrayElemAt": [ "$author", 0 ] }}, in:"$$author.name"}}`

Comment: Other option is use: `{ $unwind:"$author" }` between `{$lookup: ...}` and `{$project: ...}`

Comment: `$unwind` will work too in your case as you have one to one mapping but in case of one to many mapping you will need `$group` stage to put everything back together as array.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. Thanks.